# Kibana No results found for my index pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I insert this pattern to find my object when I search in kibana

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/exception_index?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "mappings": {
    "siam_exception": { 
      "dynamic": "true", 
      "properties": { 
        "Title":    { "type": "text"  }, 
        "Date&Time":     { "type": "text"  },
        "Tags":     { "type": "text"  },
        "Level":     { "type": "text"  },  
        "Message":     { 
         "dynamic": "true", 
         "properties": { 
           "Root":      { "type": "text" },  
           "ExceptionList":      { "type": "text" } 
          }
        }    
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

and this is my exception.log

```
"siam_exception":{
 "Title": "exception",
 "Date&Time": "2018-01-21 09:52:20.759950",
 "Tags": "SiamCore",
 "Level": "Fatal", 
 "Message":[
   {
     "Root": "( ['MQROOT' : 0x7f0a902b2d80]
  (0x01000000:Name  ):Properties = ( ['MQPROPERTYPARSER' : 0x7f0a902bffa0]
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MessageSet             = 'SIAMCOMMONMSG' (CHARACTER)",

     "ExceptionList": "(0x03000000:NameValue):ReplyIdentifier        = X'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' (BLOB)","
   }
 ] 
}
```

but kibana find nothing when I search *
even if I omit ' "siam_exception": ' from first line of exception.log nothing change
what is my problem

Comment: Looks like you don't have documents in the index. Are you sure your ES index contains data?

Comment: curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
   "query": {
       "query_string" : {
           "default_field": "Message.Root",
           "query" : "test*"
       }
   }
}
'   it return data when I manually  put data to elasticsearch. but It doens not work when it come from exception.log

Comment: run a simpler: `curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices?pretty` please

Comment: "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "exception_index",
        "_type" : "siam_exception",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "Title" : "This doc adds a new field",
          "Date&Time" : "2018-01-21 09:52:20.654654",
          "Tags" : [
            "SiamCore",
            "SiamGetaway"
          ],
          "Level" : "Fatal",
          "Message" : [
            {
              "Root" : " test 1111",
              "ExceptionList" : "test1"
            }
          ]

Comment: yellow open exception_index     el6BhZjASvieULHCd3DzRw 5 1    0 0    650b    650b

Comment: ok good, what are you exactly entering in kibana as an index pattern?

Comment: exception_index, it load OK, but when I search kibana didn't found anything

Comment: is there any solution?? it really drive my crazy

Comment: My only guess is that the document inside the index is not considered valid by kibana because it is missing some needed data, such as the "@timestamp" field and probably even others. But again, it's only a guess.

Comment: I really appropriate if you create an pattern form me to find "siam_exception" object. thank you